# Problem producing pounds symbol (£) in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols

I'm having trouble getting a pounds symbol to appear in math-mode contexts in my document. The problem seems to be the use of the newpxtext package. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

$\pounds$

\end{document}
```

When I typeset the above, I just get a blank instead of the pounds symbol. Any advice on how to make it display?

Comment: Odd. It works for me using TeXLive 2015 (MacTeX). You could try `$\hbox{\pounds}$`, though that does not answer the question why it works for me but not for you.

Comment: well I first tried in on overleaf and it failed to work as described in the question, however, on a fully uptodate texlive 2015 it indeed works fine. Make sure you distribution is uptodate. Oh and Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Compiles without errors and warnings in current MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: I tried with TeX Live 2014 and indeed the pounds sign doesn't appear. However, since it's a text command, it should be inside `\mbox` anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `\pounds` is found in math mode, LaTeX executes `\mathsterling`, otherwise it does `\textsterling`.

If we look at `newpxtext.sty` in a TeX Live 2014 distribution, we find

```
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\mathsterling}{\mathord}{operators}{163}
```

The package is version 1.232, released 2015/04/07. This line is commented out in the current version 1.293 released 2015/08/07.

With your code compiled on a system using version 1.232 or earlier, the code points to the character in slot 163 of Computer Modern Roman (`cmr10`), because this is the font used for operators; but the font has nothing beyond slot 127.

It's even worse if you also load `newpxmath`, because you'll find `č` instead of the sterling symbol, because the normal text font in T1 encoding is used and in slot 163 one finds č.

The line was a remnant of `pxfonts.sty`, because the text font selected by this package indeed had a sterling symbol in that slot.

### Solutions

1. Preferred: upgrade your TeX system and *always* load `newpxmath` along with `newpxtext`.
2. Temporary: load `newpxmath` and add manually to your preamble the current definition of `\mathsterling`, that is,

   ```
   \renewcommand{\mathsterling}{\mbox{\textsterling}}
   ```

To be honest, I don't find this new definition particularly appealing, because the symbol would not scale in subscripts/superscripts.

If you need an italic sterling in math mode, scaling in subscripts/superscripts, whatever is your TeX distribution, add

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\mathsterling}{\text{\normalfont\itshape\textsterling}}
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\renewcommand{\mathsterling}{\text{\normalfont\itshape\textsterling}}

\begin{document}

$\pounds_{\pounds}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The output is the same using an older TeX distribution (I tested it with TL 2012, 2013 and 2014).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your TeX distribution, the text-mode and math-mode renditions of `\pounds` may differ. I get the following output from running your code on a system with MacTeX2015 and version 1.293 (2015/08/07) of `newpxtext`:

[image]

Since `newpxmath` isn't loaded, the symbol produced by `$\pounds$` is the math-italic glyph from the Computer Modern font family.

If the `newpxmath` package were loaded as, all three glyphs would be the same, at least on my system.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\pounds, $\mbox{\pounds}$, $\pounds$
\end{document}
```